# i double clicked on a button in eclipse for android program but the source code is not appearing instead xml is opening

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

I double clicked on a button in eclipse for android program but the source code is not appearing instead XML part is opening.I am unable to write code for controlling the button
please help in solving my problem.
thanks in advance...

Comment: which IDE are you using?

Comment: eclipse ide downloaded recently online

Comment: @Aakash it says in the title, body, and tag Eclipse so....

Comment: please answer and stop rating it as unclear question.

Comment: if u have any doubts ask me through the comments

Comment: sorry for my behaviour.
Iam on a project so i need an answer as quick as possible

Comment: Maybe you could provide more detail. *"I double clicked on a button in eclipse"* what button? Maybe a screen shot of what you are seeing?

Comment: i have created a button in GUI and adjusted its position as reqiured

Answer (score 0):

u must be working with android design view in eclipse so it is obvious when u click on the button on design view this will take u to the xml part which is used for developing GUI part..
android eclipse or studio does not generate a java code for button or something else..
[click here to see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKOVS.png)

hope this helps u..

Comment: but previously i am redirected to the code which is already regenerated

Comment: what's happening now ?

Comment: i am not getting clearly what u did,but when u press ctrl+(filename writtened in a code line) of java u r taken to that file in android studio

Comment: i am using eclipse
i created an android project
in .java file, automatically a code should be generated when i double click on my layout .But its not happening here

Comment: then should we write the entire code for actionListener??